# What is a Proj.-Tessar lens?

Tags: terminology, optics, zeiss

I recently picked up a lens and an estate sale. 
"Carl Zeiss Jena No907646 proj-tessar 1:4,5 f=13,5cm."
The 'proj' prefix led me to believe that it's a projector lens, but I'm not sure what kind of projector would use a 135mm worth of throw.

[image]

Comment: Projector sounds right - it would give us some clues if you can post an image of what you've bought.

Comment: I can't provide a definitive answer, but a bit of googling found it was used as an enlarger lens.

Comment: From some more googling, it appears they were also used (in a different mount with an iris) for large format photography; for example https://picclick.ca/Proj-TESSAR-145-f-135-cm-N-252612567466.html

Answer (score 1):

Proj likely stands for projector. 135mm isn't the "throw" of the lens (distance from lens to the screen), but the distance between the slide and the lens. It is like using a camera in reverse.

[Tessar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessar) is a 4-element, 3-group lens design.